# Order of attributes in a class

Tags: python, oop, wtforms

In python is guaranteed that the order of attributes in a class is maintained? How this is guaranteed? Where in manual is specified?

This defines the fields declaratively as class attributes:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    first_name = TextField(u'First Name', validators=[validators.required()])
    last_name  = TextField(u'Last Name', validators=[validators.optional()])
    ...


def get(self):
    form = MyForm(self.request.arguments)
    form=form
    self.render('forms.html', form=form)
```

First name will be always the first item and the last name the second, even if i have *n* items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the order of attributes is normally *not* guaranteed, as Python stores attributes in a dictionary.

Instead, `wtforms` uses special tricks to detect in what order fields were defined, that work around this. Every time you create a `Field` object, a counter is incremented and a unique number is assigned to the field instance. This makes the objects orderable:

```
class UnboundField(object):
    _formfield = True
    creation_counter = 0

    def __init__(self, field_class, *args, **kwargs):
        UnboundField.creation_counter += 1
        # [...]
        self.creation_counter = UnboundField.creation_counter
```

So the `Field` instances have a `creation_counter` value that is incremented each time a new field is added to a form.

The `FormMeta` class then uses that value on the fields to sort them in the correct order:

```
fields.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1].creation_counter, x[0]))
```

Comment: For those who are interested in a detailed explanation of this, I recommend Marty Alchin's book *Pro Django* which goes into some depth.

Comment: Of course, this was prior to the `__prepare__` method in 3.x which allows changing the underlying method used for attribute look up (such as an OrderedDict)...

Comment: In tornado do you know how this is processed? The order apparently is guaranteed with some internal stuff i think.

Comment: @JonClements: sure, but anything that has to work on Python 2 still has to use their own methods. :-)

Comment: @user455318: how what is processed? Tornado most likely uses similar techniques to give objects a sequence number.

Comment: @user455318: You'll need to give us more specific code to be able to tell what you are talking about here. The code you posted is for Django, not Tornado, AFAICT.

Comment: the code is from my app with wtforms + tornado, i never tried django. I am interested to know how tornado maintain the order of attributes internally. thanks

Comment: @user455318: Ah, yes, `wtforms` closely follows the Django conventions. I'll take a look, they most likely use the *exact same* methods.

Comment: But python 2.7 has the OrderedDict. Why the order is not guaranteed with that?

Comment: @user455318: Because you cannot make a *class* use an ordered dictionary. You can do that in Python 3.3, but not in Python 2.

Comment: @user455318: updated to include the actual `wtforms` implementation of the counter.

Answer (score 1):

A new class is created by instantiating a metaclass, pretty much like you create a new instance object by instantiating the class. A class statement like:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    first_name = TextField(u'First Name', validators=[validators.required()])
    last_name  = TextField(u'Last Name', validators=[validators.optional()])
```

Is equivalent to the following call, where `type` is the default python metaclass:

```
MyForm = type('MyForm', (Form,), {'first_name': TextField(u'First Name', validators=[validators.required()]), 
                                  'last_name': TextField(u'Last Name', validators=[validators.optional()])}
```

Since the class namespace is passed forward as a dict, and dicts have an arbitrary ordering, the order is not preserved.

One way to keep the order recorded somewhere is by having the `TextField` class itself registering the order in which it was called for each set of parameters. Then you can recover the order in which the fields were declared. This is probably what Django does under the hood.